# Store data into neo4j from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, neo4j, tinkerpop, graphml

I have a `gml` file that I read it with java in eclipse and I want to know how to store the result of the code below in `neo4j`:

```
   TinkerGraph graph = new TinkerGraph();
   GMLReader gml= new GMLReader(graph);
   gml.inputGraph("/home/salma/Desktop/celegansneural.gml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import graphml and other formats from the neo4j shell with the help of the following:
https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools

Then just open the shell and use the command:

```
import-graphml -it /home/salma/Desktop/celegansneural.gml
```

The -t option tells it to import the node labels as well.

Comment: the command gives me error : 
neo4j-sh (?)$ import-graphml -it /home/salma/Desktop/celegansneural.gml 
Unknown command 'import-graphml'

Comment: neo4j-sh (?)$ import-graphml -it /home/salma/Desktop/celegansneural.gml Unknown command 'import-graphml'

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the link that I provided?

Comment: i thought the installation of neo4j-shell-tools was not necessary so i didn't do it that's why it gives the unkown command error! but now i follow all the steps including the installation part and it gives me this :  
GraphML-Import file /home/salma/Desktop/celegansneural.gml rel-type RELATED_TO batch-size 40000 use disk-cache false
finish after 0 row(s)  0. 0%: nodes = 0 rels = 0 properties = 0 time 208 ms total 208 ms
ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
 Can you please  tell me what means this result

Comment: The file should be proper graphml. It should begin like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns      http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">   <graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">

Comment: If your graph is directed change edgedefault

Comment: ok it works now i was working with file .gml but when i worked with the xml extension for the same file it works , thank you for the help

Comment: @aburski is there a way to import the gml file not the xml ?